# Displaying modal in JavaScript not transitioning smoothly

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I pinched a css effect that I like for some popup modals in my application, but I'm having some trouble when the modal(s) are created in the DOM in JS.

When the user clicks on the button to 'open' the modal, it should transition smoothly, appearing to grow in size (scaling up). When it's just html and css this works as desired, however when it's on a click event in JS that I've written, the modal just abruptly appears and disappears (if I use 'display: block'), or it's super-jerky or I can't make it work at all (if I use 'visibility: visible').

My feeling is that it isn't viewing it as a 'transition' and the effect doesn't apply, or that I'm somehow trying to transition the blurred background rather than the modal element.

This is my css.....

```
.modal {
  display: none; <-- added to flip between states, might be cause of problem

  height: 100vh; 
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; 
  background-color: rgba($color-black, .8);
  z-index: 999999;
  opacity: .98; 
  transition: all .3s;

  @supports(-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px)) or (backdrop-filter:blur(10px)){
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    background-color: rgba($color-black, .3);
  }

  &__content {
    @include absCenter; 
    width: 75%; 
    background-color: $color-white;
    box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba($color-black, .2);
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: table; 
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 1; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    transition: all .5s .2s;
  }
```

Please forgive the (very) pseudo code for the JS, but the actual code is spaghetti like mama used to make.....

```
dbRecord.forEach(el => {
   const button = document.createElement('button')
   button.innerHTML = <populate some html with db info>

   button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
         modal.style.display = 'block' 
         modal.innerHTML = <set attributes from parent element>

         document.querySelector('.modalCloseButton').addEventListener('click') => {
                modal.style.display = 'none'
         }
         ...
  }
}
```

How can I make this transition smooth rather than abrupt?

Comment: Use `background` and `color` for the transitions. Check my answer for more information. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62810810/13800918

Comment: The answer you got is pretty cool. Another idea is changing the visibility property which does transition

Answer (score 3):

I got the transition working only one way. Maybe this code sample helps you to get it also working the other way.
`display` can't have transitions. Set `background` and `color` to `transparent`. When your transition time is `0.3s` make a `setTimeout` to set it to `display: none` after 0.3 seconds.

```js
var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
var dbRecord = ['foo', 'bar']
dbRecord.forEach(el => {
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = 'populate some html with db info<br>' + el;

  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    modal.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'set attributes from parent element<br>' + el;
    document.querySelector('.modalCloseButton').style.display = 'block';
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    modal.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,.8)';
    modal.style.color = 'white';

  });
  document.body.appendChild(button);
});
document.querySelector('.modalCloseButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
  modal.style.color = 'transparent';
  document.querySelector('.modalCloseButton').style.display = 'none';
  setTimeout(() => {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }, 300)
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 999999;
  color: transparent;
  transition: all .3s linear 0s;
}
.modalCloseButton {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <p></p>
  <button class="modalCloseButton">&times;</button>
</div>
```